# PHP - Extract data from Http Post (Angular)

Tags: php, angular, http, post

I have this function (angular) to send information to php page:

```
public SendData(cart_items:any) {
  const jsonContent = new RequestOptions({
    headers:new Headers({ 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
    })
  });
  let body = JSON.stringify(cart_items);
        return this.http.post("xxxxxxxxxx/pay.php", body, jsonContent)
            .map(result => {
            return result.json();
        }); 
    }
```

how can i get access to data in the page 'pay.php'

Comment: Have you tried anything yet, you should catch post in your php file, and decode it.

Comment: @DenisSolakovic i don't know witch value have i to decode it, ` $obj = json_decode($???, true);`

Comment: @Fray, firstly try to debug it, `var_dump($_POST); exit; `, so you could see is there something in that post variable, and then decode that content.

Comment: @DenisSolakovic i got this : ` array(0) {
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a pure php question, but you do this:

```
 $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $obj = json_decode($json, true);
    $name = $obj['name'];
    $age = $obj['age'];
```

This would work if the object you're posting is like this:
{
   "name":"My Name",
   "age":"24"
}